# Making page load older posts on scroll down

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to make my site automatically load older posts on scroll down. I have tried various tutorials/plugins for 5 hours now but I just can't make it work so any help would be SO MUCH appreciated :)

[This Tutorial][1] seems like the best solution so I integrated everything in my functions.php, tried messing with all the variables and absolutely everything i can think of,

But .... NOTHING happens.

**This is the tutorial code i added to my functions.php :**

Why doesn't it work? Again, Thanks so much for any help!

EDIT : SOLVED

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the line which initializes that plugin:

```
jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll( infinite_scroll );
```

inside the :

```
jQuery(window).load(function($){
    // somewhere in here
    jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll( infinite_scroll );
});
```

so it executes only after the document has loaded, since it seems you are trying to access the library before the actual `js` file has finished loading

**UPDATE:**

Just checked your website and it seems the included `js` file for this plugin is not the actual library but something else. See:

> http://sparschweinkiller.de/wp-content/themes/gridly2/js/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js

This should actually be replaced by the js library

Comment: I wasn't sure where exactly you meant so i di it like this. Does not work. (new code in answer)

Comment: Add all of 3 lines: `jQuery(window).load....` so it's wrapped by the jquery on document load event

Comment: isnt that exactly what i have done? look at the code in the answer.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your help but which one would you say is the correct one? I downloaded the file from here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/master/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js

- as it is recommended in the tutorial

Comment: Yes that should be fine as it seems to be the official git for that plugin and you are downloading the master branch.